# How can I combine this php category_name filter?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a semi beginner wordpress php developer, and I try to combine 2 different `category_name` here.

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'showposts'     => 2,
    'category_name' => $post->post_name,
    'category_name' => 'featured',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
);
```

I guess that I may need to combine the 2 category_name here. Do you know how to do it?

I want to know if it is possible to have 2 different types of filters under the same `category_name`.

Comment: what is this args for? wp_query?

Comment: You can use `'category_name' => 'featured+' . $post->post_name,` (note the `+`). However, is `$post->post_name` a valid category?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_cat_ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_id/) to get the ID of the category name.

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'project',
    'showposts'    => 2,
    'category__in' => array( get_cat_ID( $post->post_name ), get_cat_ID( 'featured' ) ),
    'orderby'      => 'menu_order',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Check this page for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters


$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'project',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'orderby'      => 'title',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-1',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-2',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-3',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-4',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-5',
        ),
    )
    
);
```